# spark structured streaming for XML files

Tags: apache-spark-xml

I am trying to parse an xml files using `spark xml databricks package`(`spark-xml_2.11` of `com.databricks`) using `structred` streaming (`spark.readStream--`).

While performing `readstream` operation, it is saying like unsupported operation "`readstream`".

Please advice any plans to support this or other alternative to achieve xml streaming.

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE]. Show us exactly what you have tried and exactly what the error message reads. "Saying like" doesn't get it.